# Printer gets IP from dhcpd but can't be pinged?

Tags: printer, dhcp, ping

My dhcpd server sees the printer on the LAN. It receives a DISCOVER, and will assign it an IP:

```
dhcpd[1378]: DHCPOFFER on 10.1.0.11 to 00:26:73:75:a8:79 via br0
dhcpd[1378]: DHCPREQUEST for 10.1.0.11 (10.1.0.1) from 00:26:73:75:a8:79 via br0
dhcpd[1378]: DHCPACK on 10.1.0.11 to 00:26:73:75:a8:79 via br0
```

Still, after this, I cannot ping the printer at the assigned address. Nor does printing work.

Is every printer supposed to respond to pings?

The printer is a [Ricoh SP 3510DN](https://www.ricoh.ca/en/products/pd/equipment/printers-and-copiers/printers/sp-3510dn-black-and-white-laser-printer) with 100Mbps ethernet that is connected to my dhcpd server via a 2.5Gbps unmanaged switch: [qsw-1105-5t](https://www.qnap.com/en-us/product/qsw-1105-5t#).

The fact that dhcp negotiations are going on leads me to believe that the network is behaving properly. So why can't the ping get through? All other devices on my LAN are perfectly ping-able.

With brctrl I see that the MAC addr of the printer is active every 26s or so according to the ageing timer. Even if there is a 1s ping to it in progress.

### Update 1

The plot thickens: I followed the suggestion of trying arping and that does respond:

```
root@Workstation:/var/log# ping 10.1.0.11
PING 10.1.0.11 (10.1.0.11) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- 10.1.0.11 ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 4102ms

root@Workstation:/var/log# arping 10.1.0.11
ARPING 10.1.0.11
60 bytes from 00:26:73:75:a8:79 (10.1.0.11): index=0 time=201.697 usec
60 bytes from 00:26:73:75:a8:79 (10.1.0.11): index=1 time=198.640 usec
60 bytes from 00:26:73:75:a8:79 (10.1.0.11): index=2 time=199.352 usec
```

In addition to that, I've found that if I re-configure the printer with a manual IP setting (even though it is the same 10.1.0.11/255.253.0.0) it will start responding to a regular ping as well.

I'm puzzled. I guess I can keep the manual IP config, but it makes no sense to me?

Comment: Can you try pinging from another device.  I usually deal with HP Printers and they can all be pinged properly.

Comment: Simplify and test it yourself: connect the printer directly to a computer and run DHCP on it. If you don't want to mess with system configuration, boot OPNsense live USB - it will run in RAM. Then try to ping the printer. There's nothing mandating a printer to respond to pings, although it could simplify troubleshooting greatly in some scenarios.

Comment: Does the printer respond to `arping`?

Comment: @user1686 The arping succeeds.  To gronostaj I already am using a PC (w Ubuntu) as my home router.

Comment: In that case, are you sure the printer is _configured_ to respond to pings? Also, when you ping it, what packets (if any) show up from the printer on a packet capture?